# Looking for help in developing a better intuition about this Lagrange Multiplier Problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

The question asks:

> The plane $x+y+2z\:=2$ intersects the paraboloid $z\:=x^{2\:}+y^2$.
>   Find the points on this ellipse that are nearest to and farthest to
>   the origin.

So this is a problem on a sample final for an upcoming exam. I can tell that it's a more sophisticated problem designed to test several concepts in my multivariable class. I feel comfortable with more straightforward Lagrange problems, especially when the constraint(s) are explicitly defined, but this sort of problem is a little tough for me to wrap my head around. What exactly is the objective function (and what are the constraint(s))?

I have a solution written by a TA for this particular question. It states that there are two constraints, and that the objective function is $x^2 + y^2 + z^2$, which I believe is used to describe the ellipse. Could anyone give me tips for identifying (or discovering) what the objective function of this kind of problem is? My first thought would be that the plane function is being constrained by the paraboloid it's intersecting, but I guess I need to think about these kinds of problems in terms of what we are maximizing and minimizing.

Comment: The objective function is the square of the distance from the origin, which I’m sure you’ve used in many other such problems. The key part of the TA’s solution is that instead of trying to compute the intersection of the two surfaces directly, you use each individual surface equation as a constraint and so have two Lagrange multipliers to work with.

Comment: Is there an advantage to either technique? And when you refer to the 'square of the distance from the origin' do you mean the standard distance formula (with 0,0,0 provided as destination)? I suppose you would use that as the objective and then the other two formulas as constraints?

Comment: If you can quickly find a nice formula for the intersection, then working with fewer multipliers is usually simpler. For other problems, by the time you’ve worked out an equation for the intersection, you could’ve already solved the problem with multiple constraints directly. It’s not immediately clear to me which is easier for this problem, since you can find the projection of the ellipse onto the $x$-$y$ plane easily enough, from which it’s not hard to come up with a parameterization of it.

Comment: And yes, your objective function would be the standard distance formula, squared for convenience, and the two constraints would be the equations of the surfaces. If both constraints are satisfied, the point obviously lies on the intersection of the surfaces.

Comment: Thank you @amd, I'm happy to know I can tackle this in several different ways.